# Python re module, length of occurrence of a word

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have regex like

```
m=re.search('z+',"i want to zzz zzzzzzz this is end")
```

how to find the length of consicutive z ignoring spaces 10(3z+7z)

```
"example str want to zz z this is end" ->3(2+1)
```

I am new here, please comment if anything is missing

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a slightly different regular expression, like `z[z ]*` to return a string of z's and spaces, and then use `s.count()` to count how many z's there were:

```
matches = re.findall("z[z ]*", "i want to zzz zzzzzz this is end")
result = [s.count('z') for s in matches]
print( result )
```

Output:

```
[9]
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, it helped a lot, is there any way to count spaces in between z as well, like 1 space in above case, if "zzz zzz zz" 2 like that

Comment: for both z and space counts: `result = [(s.count('z'), s.count(' ')) for s in matches]` e.g. `[(9, 1)]`

Comment: If you wanted that, why didn't you say so?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `findall` method instead, it will return all matching occurrences. Then you need to map the Len function to return length of the matched substrings of z, and later you can get both it and it's sum:

```
m=re.findall('z+',"i want to zzz zzzzzzz this is end")
m=list(map(len,m))
print(sum(m),m)
```

Comment: That will count ALL the z's, whether consecutive or not (which `m.count('z')` would also do).  He should have provided a counter example, like "hey hey zzz hey hey zzz zzz zzz" should presumably return 3 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import re
matches = re.findall("z+(?:\s+z+)*", "i want to zzz zzzzzz this is end")
z_count = [(s, s.count('z')) for s in matches]
wht_count = [(s, len(s) - s.count('z')) for s in matches]
print( f'Z count: {z_count}\nWhitespace count: {wht_count}' )
# => 
##    Z count: [('zzz zzzzzz', 9)]
##    Whitespace count: [('zzz zzzzzz', 1)]
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/sCazLb).

Please note that `z+(?:\s+z+)*` regex won't capture any leading/trailing whitespace, so the number of spaces will be correct.

The regex matches

- `z+` - one or more `z` letters
- `(?:\s+z+)*` - zero or more repetitions of one or more whitespace and one or more letters `z`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MfL6Fl/1).